# How to apply String functions in Advancedatagrid itemRenderer

Tags: flex3

Is it possible to get right of "~" char in advance datagrid column ? I've tried itemRenderer property but no success. For example, I want to remove all repeated occurrence of "102.Dangerous Flora" and just to keep right of "~".

ArrayCollection is set as data provide for the grid.

[alt text http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_T_-j3ZLqfNQ/TE6C_dgi6mI/AAAAAAAABqU/LFNf_bOK3zQ/s1600/3.PNG](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_T_-j3ZLqfNQ/TE6C_dgi6mI/AAAAAAAABqU/LFNf_bOK3zQ/s1600/3.PNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this.....

for that sign use these without space

& # 126 ;